# PHP: How to get a random value between 2 users ID

Tags: php, random

I have selected two users with their id.

eg:

```
$user_one = 1034;
$user_two = 1098;
$new_id = "";
```

Now I want to select one of these two users **randomly**. Can someone please help me how to select random ids from given ids.

eg:

```
$new_id = $get_random_id  //Must be 1034 or 1098
```

Comment: Your example is not very random if it has to be `//Must be 1034 or 1038`...is the `1038` supposed to read `1098`?

Comment: Also, is it supposed to be either one of those two numbers (if supposed to be `1098`) randomly or a number from a range between those two numbers randomly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
$new_id = rand(0, 1) ? $user_one : $user_two;
```

`rand(0,1)` gives you either 0 or 1, randomly, which will evaluate to `true` or `false` to pick one or the other of the ternary outcomes, randomly.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as the question was misinterpret, here's an updated answer on how you can get a random ID from the two:

Put them into an array and use `array_rand()`.

```
$user_one = 1034;
$user_two = 1098;

$ids = array();
$ids[] = $user_one; 
$ids[] = $user_two; 
$new_id = $ids[array_rand($ids)];
```

- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/g5EiB)
- [PHP.net on `array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: Beat me to it!!

Comment: Hehe, straight home from vacation - full of energy, and quick on the draw! ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: hey i think you didn't understand my question.... i want value from these two id's .. it must be 1034 or 1098....

Comment: @Joe To be fair, your question had a typo when first posted and, at first glance reads like this answer suggests.

Comment: I thought it was this at first too.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect what you asked for. Initially, you said *between* - which is why there was a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to choose one user from given users ( not between users)

```
 // create an array with all the users ( assuming if the users are more than 2)
    $user_array = array($user_one,$user_two);
    // get a random key from array
    $random_key = array_rand($user_array, 1);
    // get value of random key
    $new_id = $user_array[$random_key];
```